# Rails error message 'The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have 2 models, Product and Cart

Here are their columns

Product (name, image, intro_image_1, intro_image_2, ...etc)

Cart(user_id, product_id, product_amounts,  ...etc)

In CartController, I join these table with below code

```
@cart_product = Cart.left_outer_joins(:product).select('carts.*, products.name, products.description, products.image, products.price, products.remain_amount').where(cart_type: 'UNCONFIRMED')

@carts = @cart_product.all
```

And in View (cart/index.html.erb), when I call @carts image by

```
<% @carts.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
    <%= image_tag(item.image, :class => 'img-responsive')%>
<% end %>
```

It shows the error message like this

[image]

But if I call Product directly, it can show image without error.

Can someone give me advices to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried assets precompile ?

Comment: Did you checked that the image is present or not in your public folder?

Comment: In my project, I upload image with carrierwave, so yes, when i upload, the image is stored in /public/uploads/product/image/{product_id}/product-xx.jpg

Comment: <%= image_tag item.image.url %> try this  one.

Comment: And what is your code for image in product view?